# SSH connection fails depending on machine type

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

When I create a default n1-standard-1 datalab instance everything works fine. But when I specify a n1-standard-32 box I cannot connect - PuTTY Fatal Error - Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey). I have tried deleting and recreating the n1-standard-32 box with the same error. I also created a new n1-standard-1 box and this connected with no issues so I don't believe my local config changed, the problem seems to be based on just the machine type.

Comment: What version of Datalab are you using and what version was used to create your instance? You can find the version of Datalab you have installed by running `gcloud version`, and you can see the version used to create your instance by adding the `--diagnose-me` flag to your `datalab connect` command.

Comment: 20180823 to both create and connect. I was able to create and use an n1-standard-16 instance for the project I'm working on.